# Rails query: Compare calculation of two attribute values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.1, ruby-2.1

I have a model, Product, which has both a `:created_at` timestamp and an `:expiration_in_days` attribute. Products are considered expired a certain number of days after their creation. How do I write a query that only returns products that have not expired?

Rails 4, Ruby 2.1, PG 0.17

I have been trying queries like this, with no success:

```
#product.rb
def self.not_expired
  where('created_at + expiration_in_days * 86400 >= ?', Time.now)
end
```

I have a pure Ruby version that works fine, it's just slower:

```
#product.rb
def self.not_expired
  select{ |p| (p.created_at.to_i + p.expiration_in_days * 86400) >= Time.now.to_i}
end
```

- *note, the 86400 calculation converts the the :expiration_in_days integer into seconds*

Any pointers on more advanced Rails queries than the documentation (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) would be very welcome as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def self.not_expired
  where("created_at + (expiration_in_days * 86400)::text::interval >= ?", Time.now)
end
```

**UPDATE**: Add references

You can learn more about date and time function [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html).

Given your case has a special requirement, which is the value of `expiration_in_days` is a column in the table, we cannot use `created_at + interval expiration_in_days day`. Instead, we need to [type cast](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC) its value to `interval`. But you can't type cast straight to an integer, that's why we cast it to `text` first.

Comment: And tests are passing, that works. Thank you. I have absolutely no idea where I would have learned to do that, though. Any suggestions for resources on this?

Comment: Hi @steel, I've updated the answer with some references. HTH!

Answer (score 0):

A + B > C is true if A <= C - B

So, instead of trying to add the expiration time to created_at, subtract the expiration time from Time.now.

```
def expiration_threshold
  Time.now - amount_of_time # I'm not sure what type to use
end

def self.not_expired
  where( "created_at > ? ", expiration_threshold )
end
```

I've always been a little stumped about what type Rails/Ruby will want when dealing with various dates/times, you may have to play around.

Comment: The problem is the expiration threshold is different for every record. I'm not sure how this addresses that.

Comment: Ah ha.  Thats an issue for my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work but try something like this

```
def self.not_expired
  where("TIMESTAMP created_at + INTERVAL '1 day' * expiration_in_days >= NOW()")
end
```